# button count down enable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a button inside a modal that have a countdown, at first it is disabled (is true), but after the countdown it turns disable.

If I leave the button countdown untill the end, and then I test it again (closing my modal and open it again), it starts the countdown over again, it works fine up to now.

But it has a strange bug.

If in the middle of the countdown, I close the modal and then open it again, my countdown restarts but it goes imedially to the end of the countdown, it doesn't go through all the numbers.

Here is my code:

html:

```
<button 
    ng-click="wizardCtrl.callModal()" 
    id="btn-unblock"
    ng-disabled="wizardCtrl.unblock"
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-medium @{{ wizardCtrl.btn }}"
    href=""
>
    Wait @{{wizardCtrl.message}} seconds
</button>
```

controller:

```
vm.unblock = true;

function unblockButton() {
    debugger;
    vm.c = 5;
    vm.message = vm.c;

    var timer = $interval(function() {

        vm.message = vm.c;
        vm.c--;

        if(vm.c<0) {
            $interval.cancel(timer);
            vm.unblock = false;
            angular.element('#btn-unblock').text("Desbloquear e Ver");
            vm.btn = "btn-green";
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You typed "`at first it is disabled (is true), but after the countdown it turns disable.`" Is one of those `disabled` supposed to be `enable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When closing the modal, you should also abort the interval. It is still running when you open the modal up again, so it will affect the second modal. Alternatively check if an interval is set and clear it before opening.

Comment: your right, in my close button modal i set it to $interval.cancel(vm.timer);

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the timer and the button before you start the timer.

```
vm.unblock = true;

// Make your timer variable global
var timer = null;

function unblockButton() {
    debugger;
    vm.c = 5;
    vm.message = vm.c;

    // Clear old timer
    $interval.cancel(timer);

    // Block the button
    vm.unblock = true; // Check this part of code...
    vm.btn = "btn-red"; // This too...

    // Start new timer
    timer = $interval(function() {

        vm.message = vm.c;
        vm.c--;

        if(vm.c<0) {
            $interval.cancel(timer);
            vm.unblock = false;
            angular.element('#btn-unblock').text("Desbloquear e Ver");
            vm.btn = "btn-green";
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```